# One Way Binding Angular2 Component With Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angular

I was building an angular2 app in the expected language of typescript and I was having a ton of problem with 3rd-party typings and I was pulling my hair out with dealing with these typescript issue. So I **boldly** decided to instead give it a try in pure javascript. Crazy huh? Given the extreme lack of help to be found on the web.

But everything is working great with one exception, I can't get one way binding on a control to work. I am using an ES7 transpiler and so some of the annotations even work! So in the end it looks fairly similar to typescript (except for the typing of course).

#### app component html snippet

```
<results [results]="results"></results>
```

#### ResultsComponent

```
@Component({
    selector: 'results',
    templateUrl: '<div *ngFor="let result of results"><result [result]="result"></result></div>',
    directives: [ResultComponent]
})
export class ResultsComponent {
    @Input() results;
    constructor(){};
}
```

In Typescript this was working fine. The results property in my ResultsComponent would be set to the value set in the app component. In the pure javascript version results is **null**. The code is reacting to the @Input decorator because if I take it away it complains about it being missing

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'results' since it isn't a known native property

but somehow the data is not coming through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the inputs section of the Component decorator thanks to [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/). I changed ...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'results',
    templateUrl: '<div *ngFor="let result of results"><result [result]="result"></result></div>',
    directives: [ResultComponent]
})
export class ResultsComponent {
    @Input() results;
    constructor(){};
}
```

... to ...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'results',
    templateUrl: '<div *ngFor="let result of results"><result [result]="result"></result></div>',
    directives: [ResultComponent],
    inputs: ['results']
})
export class ResultsComponent {
    constructor(){};
}
```

... and it works now!